# How Can I trigger Google PlaceAutocompleteFragment from a menu item?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am new to android and trying to create a list-detail app. I am trying to add the PlaceAutocompleteFragment for searching and adding places to my list.

Now I wanted to add the PlaceAutocompleteFragment to my app and trigger it in such a way that the search dialog gets invoked if I click a plus ("+") sign on my actionbar's menu item.

Instead I am only able to manage to add the PlaceAutocompleteFragment to my list activity's layout.

**city_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/city_list"
    android:name="com.apoorv.android.weatherapp.CityListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.apoorv.android.weatherapp.CityListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/city_list_content" />
</LinearLayout>
enter code here
```

[How it appears now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcjXO.png)

Whereas, I tried adding it to a Menu for my activity but it crashes the app with a NullPointer exception if I add the fragment to my menu.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_city_button"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:title="Add City"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</menu>
```

I want to invoke the autocomplete dialog on the click of the + sign of this menu.

[Plus Sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sczII.png)

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?